# How can I build a set using the rule "include A, OR exclude B" in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is directly related to [my previous question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459301/how-can-i-build-a-set-using-the-rule-exclude-a-or-b-in-set-theory/4459306?noredirect=1#comment9341673_4459306) about building a subset from a universal set, based on a list of "rules". The rules can be something like (given a set of numbers) "include even numbers", "exclude odd numbers", "include even numbers OR numbers greater than 5" and so on. With your help, I've defined 6 likely operations that would be applied to the universal set, given these combinations of rules:

The example universal set is the set of numbers from 1 to 10, i.e. $U=\{1\ldots10\}$:

1. "Include numbers that are even" --> $\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$
2. "Include numbers that are even AND greater than 5" --> $\{6, 8, 10\}$
3. "Include numbers that are even OR greater than 5" --> $\{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$
4. "Exclude numbers that are even" --> $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$
5. "Exclude numbers that are even AND greater than 5" --> $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9\}$
6. "Exclude numbers that are even OR greater than 5" --> $\{1, 3, 5\}$

Thanks to Connor Gordon for helping me to understand how we arrive at rule 6 - by taking the union of even numbers and numbers greater than 5, and subtracting that from the universal set:

$\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} \cup \{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} = \{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$

$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} - \{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} = \{1, 3, 5\}$

Where I've run into logical trouble is once we start mixing include and exclude rules.

7. "Include numbers that are even, AND exclude numbers greater than 3" --> $\{2\}$
8. "Include numbers that are even AND greater than 3, AND exclude numbers greater than 7" --> $\{4, 6\}$
9. "Include numbers that are even, AND exclude numbers greater than 3 AND less than 7 --> $\{2, 8, 10\}$
10. "Include numbers that are even, AND exclude numbers greater than 5 OR multiples of 3" -->

    - Include $\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$, then from that subtract $\{6\} \cup \{6, 8, 10\} = \{6, 8, 10\}$, resulting in $\{2, 4\}$
11. "Include numbers that are even OR exclude numbers greater than 5" -->

    - Exclude: $U - G = \{1\ldots10\} - \{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$
    - Include: $U \cap E = \{1\ldots10\} \cap \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$
    - Include OR Exclude: $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \cup \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10\}$

It's rule 11 that I'm not sure about, when it comes to joining include conditions and exclude conditions with "OR". I think that I need to calculate the conditions separately, and then union them together at the end. (My understanding so far from set theory is that when I need to apply an 'OR' operation I generally use union, and for an 'AND' operation it's intersection. Building a set by "inclusion" means taking a union of my subset from the universal set, and building a set by "exclusion" means subtracting (differencing) the subset from the universal set.)

Is this working correct for 7-11 (especially 11), or have I made any errors?

Comment: What is missing from [yesterday's post answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459301/how-can-i-build-a-set-using-the-rule-exclude-a-or-b-in-set-theory)?

Comment: The post answer you've linked perfectly answered the question I had yesterday, and has helped me to get a better understanding of set operations. I'm trying to work out the additional combinations of "include/exclude" rules and want to verify that my workings are correct for the additional rules defined.

Comment: It seems a bit confusing. In the example you are giving, what would happen with 2? You include it because it's even or you exclude it because it isn't greater than 5?

Comment: @AugSB I agree that it doesn't exactly sound intuitive in natural language. I wouldn't want to support it, but the current specification of the program I'm writing means that there's no reason why someone can't specify "include (condition A) OR exclude (condition B)". So looking at it from the point of view of set theory, I want to know if the answer I've come up with (union the two sets defined by 'include A' and 'exclude B' respectively) is "correct" or at least a coherent solution.

Comment: In that case, "union" seems a good approach to me.